# Как в angular 5 вывести компонент без промежуточного блока?

Tags: javascript, angular5

Я знаю один способ. Использовать компонент в качестве директивы. То есть селектор прописывать как `selector   : '[appCustomComponent]',`.
Есть какой-то более удобный способ? Настолько я помню внутрь директивы нельзя вставлять html

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под промежуточным блоком? Привидите пример.

Comment: создаю input, но при вставке в виде компонента он помещается в блок. То есть `<app-input><input type="text"></app-input>`. А нужно `<input type="text">`.

Comment: Теперь понятно! Тогда следующий вопрос - зачем вам это нужно? Просто в этом и есть суть компоненты, вы хотите эту суть поменять)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я хочу вставить свой компонент в виде обычного input, например. Не запихивать его внутрь другого блока. Да, inline-block это хорошо, но вот все равно два блока, вместо двух. В реакте сделали, не понятно, почему этого нет в ангуляре

Comment: Потому что ангулар следует парадигме web-component. Соотвественно вы создаете компоненты. Ну а компоненты находятся каждый в своем блоке. А в чем проблема с этим блоком? Чем он вам мешает?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko порою кастомизировать неудобно. В моем представлении компоненты это попытка реализации кастомных эллементов DOM. Но оригинальные элементы dom не завернуты внутри отдельных элементов div.

Comment: Компонент, это, например `<input type="date">`. Соотвественно вся логика работы каленадаря внутри инпута. Или `<video>`, вся логика храниться внтури тега. У ангулара тоже самое. В общем - способа нету.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko все еще кажется это не совсем удобным, но благодарю за ответ